# Mannkendall trend analysis for Rainfall raster in R and its interpretation

Tags: r, regression, r-raster, r-sp, trend

I am doing a trend analysis for the raster. I need this plot.

[image: Mann-Kendall trend analysis of precipitation... Colours show Sen's slope estimator units (mm y−1) for precipitation for each grid cell (1 km regular grid). Signiﬁcant trends (α= 0.1) are shown as hatched areas]

The plot is Mann-Kendalltrend analysis of annual precipitation... Colours show Sen's slope estimator units (mm y−1) for precipitation for each grid cell (1 km regular grid). Signiﬁcant trends (α= 0.1)are shown as hatched areas
So far I have the following code.

```
    ##libraries
library(raster)
library(grDevices)
library(spatialEco)

##download the data for tile with lat long
datasets<-getData('worldclim', var='prec', res=10)

##cropping to some random smaller extent
e <- as(extent(55,65,30,35), 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(e) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
datasets <- crop(datasets, e)
names(datasets)<-month.abb

##plot the data to check
plot(datasets[[1]])


result<-raster.kendall(datasets, tau = TRUE, intercept = TRUE,  p.value = TRUE,
                       z.value = TRUE, confidence = F)
names(result) <- c("slope","tau", "intercept", "p.value","z.value")

##make the significant p value shapefile
p.value <- result[[4]]
p.value[p.value >= 0.05] <- NA ##95%significance
p.value<-rasterToPolygons(p.value)
p.value <- aggregate(p.value)

##colour scale
Uniques <- cellStats(result[["slope"]],stat=unique) 
Uniques.max <- max(Uniques)
Uniques.min <- min(Uniques)
my.at <- round(seq(ceiling(Uniques.max), floor(Uniques.min), length.out= 10),0)
myColorkey <- list(at=my.at, labels=list(at=my.at)) 
levelplot(result[["slope"]],margin=F,main="slope",par.settings=RdBuTheme(),colorkey=myColorkey,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,scales = list(draw=F,tck = 0))+
  layer(sp.polygons(p.value,density=5,angle=45))
```

It gives this.

[image]

I need to verify the following.

1. Is this the correct way of computing the trend?
2. Can I interpret this slope as trend? Can I say the trend only for polygons at lower left corner are significant (<= 0.05). Even though the higher values of slope are at top right corner.
3. How to fill the polygon as inclined hatches? I used density=5,angle=45 but it is not plotted.

Comment: The example data these can clearly not be used to compute a trend in annual precipitation --- are you aware of that?

Comment: @Robert Hijmans I am aware of the fact that the monthly precipitation cannot be used for the annual trend analysis (as monthly data are autocorrelated). I did not find any easy way of getting annual precipitation so used monthly just to show my example. I am looking answers for the methodological approach if its the right way of calculating the trend (I should have used annual data) and its significance. Let me know.